# How to create a module in Python?

Tags: python, list, module

I am writing a code using multiple modules. I am really struggling trying to understand how they work and what I am doing wrong. For example, I have two modules that I am trying to use together in a "main" module (which includes my main() function)

I have put the example below. Any help is really appreciated as I am really new to python and coding and having a lot of trouble with this.

**listdata.py**

```
def my_list()
    myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    return
```

**manipulatelist.py**

```
def change_list()
    myList1 = myList[::-1]
    print(myList1)
```

**mainfunction.py**

```
import listdata
import manipulatelist

manipulatelist.change_list()
```

I receive a `NameError` saying 'myList' is not defined. I assume that the variable 'myList' from listdata.py is not being translated over, which I understand. What I am struggling with is figuring out how to get manipulatelist.py to use myList from the module listdata

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: First make sure the code works within the same file. It won't here because you have a misunderstanding about how *functions* work.

Answer (score 0):

`manipulateList()` needs to know what it is manipulating, also in your `myList` function you must state what you are returning.

Example code:

**my_list.py**

```
def myList():
    foo = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    return foo
```

**manipulate_list.py**

```
def manipulateList(some_list):
    new_list = some_list[::-1]
    print(new_list)
```

**main.py**

```
import my_list
import manipulate_list

list_one = my_list.myList()
list_two = manipulate_list.manipulateList(list_one)
```

Comment: The first two blocks of code are both in separate modules if that makes a difference?

Comment: Editing answer now :)